# fundamental theorem of algebra proof

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I have seen some proofs of the fundamental theorem of algebra using algebraic topology.

But I have seen an exercise to prove the theorem by defining this map $f_t: S^1\longrightarrow S^1$ by $f_t(z) = p(tz)/|p(tz)|$, $t $ is nonnegative real number, and $p$ is the polynomial.

> > I think the solution may base on letting $t$ go to the infinity.

I am looking forward to your ideas :)

Comment: did you see?http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra